# Find count of combination of 2 columns - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
table_user
col1      col2
123       456
124       457
125       458
126       459
127       460
128       461
123       456
123       456
123       457
```

I need to find out the combination of col1 and col2 with counts.

In above example:

```
col1      col2   count_combination
123       456    3
123       457    1
124       457    1
125       458    1
126       459    1
127       460    1
128       461    1
```

How can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With group by col1, col2:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) count_combination
from table_user
group by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple aggregation would work :

```
select co1l, col2, count(*) as count_combination
from table_user
group by co1l, col2;
```